# Cycle through array in iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, nsorderedset

In this app I save an NSOrderedSet of cards to a "Subject" entity in core data so that users can quiz themselves. The card flips and drags in tinder like fashion well but in the update card method I'm having some trouble. The current card displays fine as I set that in view did load (the first card of the NSOrderedSet's array property). When I drag and update however it immediately goes to the last card, for example if I have 5 cards in a deck it will start with the first then immediately go to the fifth. What would be the best way to update this method so that it will cycle through as desired?

I suppose I should pass it an index property like a tableViewDelegate method but if someone has done something like this before and has a better way that's greatly appreciated.

Thanks for the help like always.

```
    func updateCard() {

    //cycle through questions here

    for var i = 0; i < (self.subject.cards?.count)!; i++ {

        self.currentCard = self.subject.cards?.array[i] as? Card
        self.draggableView.questionLabel.text = self.currentCard?.question
        self.draggableView.answerLabel.text = self.currentCard?.answer

    }
}
```

Comment: google for % operator (modolo or rest operator)

Comment: Your code does not make sense, it will always end up setting the values corresponding to the last card since you overwrite the previously set ones in the next iteration. what would you want to happen in between? The answer probably will be: do not use a loop.

Comment: The code makes perfect sense, but as you said the compiler will automatically skip to the last index, I know what the problem is but thought there would be a way to loop through an array one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, when you call `updateCard` the for loop is computing at computer-speed and you only get to see the last index.

Here's one option:

In your class, set a stored variable called selectedCardIndex as an implementation detail and then just increment and update the view in `updateCard`.

```
var selectedCardIndex = 0

func updateCard() {

    self.selectedCardIndex += 1
    self.currentCard = self.subject.cards?.array[self.selectedCardIndex] as? Card
    self.draggableView.questionLabel.text = self.currentCard?.question
    self.draggableView.answerLabel.text = self.currentCard?.answer

}
```